# How do I test the aftereffects of the Node https module while allowing it to call the callback function?

Tags: node.js, sinon

I have the following code...

```
const reqSent = https.get(url, (response) => {
  if (response.statusCode == 302 || response.statusCode == 307) {
    const url = `https://${reqSent.host}${response.headers.location}`;
    NPMServer.sendRequest(url, extract);
  } else {
    response.pipe(gunzip()).pipe(extract);
  };
} ).on("error", ()=>res.status(500).send("Failed"));
```

I know I can stub with something like...

```
get = sinon.stub(https, "get")
```

What I am not sure is how do I get it to call the callback function after? That way I can test these lines...

```
if (response.statusCode == 302 || response.statusCode == 307) {
  const url = `https://${reqSent.host}${response.headers.location}`;
  NPMServer.sendRequest(url, extract);
} else {
  response.pipe(gunzip()).pipe(extract);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it it would be...

```
get = sinon.stub(https, "get")
const item = { ... }
get.getCalls()[0].args[1](item);
```

Answer (score 0):

The better is use `stub.callsArgWith(index, arg1, arg2, ...)`:

> Like `callsArg`, but with arguments to pass to the callback.

`stub.callsArg(index)`:

> Causes the stub to call the argument at the provided index as a callback function. `stub.callsArg(0)`; causes the stub to call the first argument as a callback. If the argument at the provided index is not available or is not a function, a TypeError will be thrown.

```js
const https = require('https');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('71862003', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const item = { statusCode: 200 };
    sinon.stub(https, 'get').callsArgWith(1, item);
    https.get('https://localhost:3000/api', (response) => {
      console.log('response: ', response);
    });
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(https.get, 'https://localhost:3000/api', sinon.match.func);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
  71862003
response:  { statusCode: 200 }
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (8ms)
```